# Android is killing activity while the service controlled by it lives on

Tags: android

I have an app which has a single activity which has a checkbox the starts and stops a foreground service. The activity also has some other settings which control that service.

The problem is that after some time navigating other apps the service continues to run fine but the activity gets killed. If I restart the activity the checkbox will be set to default, off. If I switch it to on, a second service starts, while the first one is still running and can't be controlled anymore.

I can't figure out how to handle this situation. It's necessary for the service to run indefinitely and there doesn't seem to be anyway to keep the activity from dying. Maybe there's a way for the new activity to find the old service?

Comment: "If I switch it to on, a second service starts, while the first one is still running and can't be controlled anymore" -- services are natural singletons; there should not be two copies running. Please post the code for the service (plus the manifest) and show where and how you are starting the service. Also indicate what evidence that you have that "the first one is still running".

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill the service in OnPause() method of your activity .that solve my problem few times ago.

Comment: I do not want to kill the service though. The service needs to live on until it's stopped by the user.

Comment: we can,t pause the service ,we can start it or stop it ..if you don,t want to Stop it ..then do nothing with the code of StopService() , by this your service will run at background .

Comment: Just check the state of the service using the code in my answer and maintain the state of the checkbox accordingly. Hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: i think you can check that service is runing or not in android .for state maintance you have to use sharedprefernces or anything else .

Comment: @deep, please check my answer it tells you How to check the state of a service, no need to use preferences to maintain it.

Comment: yes i have checked that .this ans is already on SO..i think this code is for checking the service is runing or not .

Answer (score 0):

To check if particular service is running, write the below method your activity, and call it when you want to check the state of the service

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
     ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
     for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
          if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
               return true; 
          }
     }
     return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **"service continues to run fine but the activity gets killed"**

   services are given more importance than activities, if android where given a choice to kill an activity or a service it always kill an activity first.
2. **"a second service starts"**

   services can only be started once no matter how many times you start a service.
3. **"checkbox will be set to default"**

use sharedpreferences to persist values.